# Get html from <td class"title"> and attach it to img

Tags: jquery, image, html-table

I have HTML:

```
<table id='ansichttable' class='table appels'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='bold'>Afbeelding</th>
            <th class="bold">Locatie</th>
            <th class='bold'>Groep</th>
            <th class='bold'>Soort</th>
            <th class='bold'>Bijzonderheden</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="img" href="images/imagesfruit/boomgaard4.jpg"><img src="images/imagesfruit/thumbs/t-boomgaard4.jpg"/></a></td>
            <td valign="top">Tuin</td>
            <td valign="top">Appels</td>
            <td valign="top" class="titel">Dubbele Bellefleur</td>
            <td valign="top">Zoete stevige appel</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="img" href="images/imagesfruit/boomgaard4.jpg"><img src="images/imagesfruit/thumbs/t-boomgaard4.jpg"/></a></td>
            <td valign="top">Tuin</td>
            <td valign="top">Appels</td>
            <td valign="top" class="titel">Dubbele Zoete Aagt</td>
            <td valign="top">Zoete stevige appel</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="images/imagesfruit/boomgaard4.jpg"><img src="images/imagesfruit/thumbs/t-boomgaard4.jpg"/></a></td>
            <td valign="top">Tuin</td>
            <td valign="top">Appels</td>
            <td valign="top" class="titel">Ellisons Orange</td>
            <td valign="top">Zoete stevige appel</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I am trying to create is that jQuery gets the title from the: `td class="titel"` 
and create at the a `href="......"` a title tag like this:

```
<td><a href="images/imagesfruit/boomgaard4.jpg" titel="Ellisons Orange"><img src="images/imagesfruit/thumbs/t-boomgaard4.jpg"/></a></td>
<td valign="top">Tuin</td>
<td valign="top">Appels</td>
<td valign="top" class="titel">Ellisons Orange</td>
<td valign="top">Zoete stevige appel</td>
```

I have tried the following :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var gettitle = $("td:eq(3)").html();
                 $("td a").attr("title", $('td.titel').text());
```

And:

```
$("td a.img").attr("title", $('.titel').html());
```

And:

```
$('table').each(function() {
  var title = $(this).find('td.titel').text();
  $(this).find('td a').attr('title', title);
 });
```

All of them are working, but collecting all the titles from the table and attach them to all the images.

What I need is that jQuery collects the title and attach it to the image above the td where it gets the title. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yAKYx/6/). This will put the text from each `td` with class `titel` on the `title` attribute of the `a` on the same row.

```
$('td.titel').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('a').attr('title', $(this).text()); 
});
```

Explanation of what this does:

- For each of the selected `td.titel` elements

  - Walk up the tree to the parent (in this case it's the `tr`), then down to the `a` inside that `tr`
  - Put the text of the `td.titel` element in the `title` attribute of the `a`

Answer (score 1):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/dP76b/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table tr').each(function(){
        var titleText = $(this).find('.titel').text();
        $(this).find('a.img img').attr('title', titleText);
    });
});
```

The "Ellisons Orange" image doesn't work because the corresponding `a` element does not have `class="img"`:

```
<a href="images/imagesfruit/boomgaard4.jpg"><img src="images/imagesfruit/thumbs/t-boomgaard4.jpg"/></a>
```

You can either add the `class`, or change `.find('a.img img')` to `.find('a img')`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You want to make sure you stay within context of "each" index:

```
$('table tr').each(function(i,obj){
    $('td{0} a',this).attr('title',$('td.titel',this).text());
});
```

Comment: Fantastic this works great , thnx all for the reactions , you guys solved it in 5 mins , and i was thinking about a for a week now , great job guys

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Is this what you are looking for?</strike>

```
$("td.titel").each(function(){
    $(this).html('<a href="" title="'+$(this).text()+'">'+$(this).text()+'</a>');
});
```

This gets each td with the class titel and wraps a link around it with the title attribute being the text within the td.

```
$("td.titel").each(function(){     
    $(this).parent().find('a.img').attr('title',$(this).text()); 
});
```

EDIT: haha, give the answer to the druttka.  I was writing this when he posted.